# mysql trigger for before update

Tags: mysql, sql

hi i have one question for mysql trigger for before update i want when i call sql query for update at that time i want to get old value of column and add with new value

this is my table 
[image]

i want to get wallet_balance column value before update and then add new value with old value and then update final value in this table using trigger

if i have 1800 and i get 100 then using trigger i want to update 1900 
plese help me for this question

error
[image]

Comment: Where's your code?...

Comment: i dont have trigger code, i want trigger code

Comment: Why - a simple update would seem to suffice?

Comment: Where did you are going to put the value when trigger fires.

Comment: Ah, `I want trigger code`...

Comment: table name = admin_wallet and add into wallet_balance

Comment: Before update you need the old value am i right? what you are going to do that old value? do you want to insert it into other table or something?

Comment: yes while multiple request getting wrong value @P.Salmon

Comment: see my updated question last line @reds

Comment: ok got it... i'll try some solution.

Comment: thanks take your time

Comment: Thats simple update and you do not need any trigger for the same. If you have `1800` and you get new `100` then update the column as `1800+100` why need of a trigger ?

Comment: i don't want to use php code for that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just asking somebody else to do the work for them

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER AddwalletValue
Before UPDATE ON admin_wallet  FOR EACH ROW
begin


New.wallet_balance = Old.wallet_balance + New.wallet_balance;



END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: see in my question

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this, all it does is encourage people to not make any effort to solve the problem themselves.  Stack overflow is here to help people out with knotty problems, not to do all the work for them.